# Refresh the fragment when user change settings

Tags: android

I have a main activity. From this activity user can navigate to profile and in profile user can edit settings.

**What I want is:** when the user makes changes, I want to refresh the fragment in main activity according to these changes. As I can only update the fragment that main activity is showing when that activity came to top again. So how can I tell main activity that data has change and update the UI accordingly.

So I was wondering what's is the best way to handle that kind of scenario.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: Are main and profile the fragments of a single activity? or main and profile are two different activities? Please put some java code so that it can be understood better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider creating a custom `BroadcastReceiver` inside the `Fragment` class, and on any change of settings send `Intent` with your custom `Action`.

Comment: Okay but how It would allow me to updated the fragment if fragment is not visible ?

Comment: @user2934930 work around replacing the fragment with itself using `SupportFragmentManager`.

Answer (score 0):

If profile is an activity, start it using `startActivityforResult`, and get new data in `onActivityResult` if fragment instance isn't `null` , call some method say `update` in that fragment. If fragment instance is null, create new one using new data.

If profile is another fragment in the main activity, then store the changes in `SharedPreferenceManager`. In On Resume of your `MainActivity`'s `FirstFragment` fetch data from `SharedPreferenceManager`. If it isn't same redraw that fragment else leave it.